# Display Parent Menu Item in Menu Block

Tags: navigation

I have a menu block that displays the sub-pages of a parent page. In addition to the sub-pages I would like at least the name of the parent page displayed but I cannot figure this out.

[image]

So in the image above, I would like to have 'About' displayed instead of the title of the block and with its sub-pages (children) below. It would be nice if I could do it in the block's template but I am sure it is more involved than that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer through a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2809699) in the menu block module.